.Net Blazor, .Net Core Api, and Microsoft.Identity
I have a blazor project in .net 8.0 that is using the new dual project design with a Server project and a Client (wasm) project.
Then, I have a DownstreamApi that is also written in .net 8.
I used this documentation to configure my app for the server side only portion of the identity config for calling downstream.  Don't worry about Client side just yet, we don't need it for now.
I got the structure for my config from this documentation
For the blazor app, I have it configured:
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "TenantId": "11..11",
  "ClientId": "33..33",
  "EnablePiiLogging": false, // set to true to enable PII

  // If the app calls downstream APIs
  "ClientCredentials": [
    {
      "SourceType": "ClientSecret",
      "ClientSecret": "<<omitted>>"
    }
  ],
  "SendX5C": false,

  "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL": false,

  // If the app is a web app:
  "ResetPasswordPath": "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/ResetPassword",
  "ErrorPath": "/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/Error",
  "WithSpaAuthCode": false,

  "Scopes": [ "User.ReadBasic.All", "user.read", "email" ]
},

// Downstream APIs
"DownstreamApis": [
  {
    "MyApi": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://my-api.azurewebsites.net/api",
      "Scopes": [ "api://my-api.azurewebsites.net/44..44/MyApi.Read" ]
    }
  }
]

And this is working great.  Users auth into my blazor app and the api is being called with an auth token.
The problem is that when I configured my API with Microsoft Identity, I now get back a very nondescript error:

www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token"

My configuration on my downstream api looks like this:
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "TenantId": "11..11",
  "ClientId": "44..44",
  "EnablePiiLogging": false, // set to true to enable PII

  // If the app calls downstream APIs
  "ClientCredentials": [
   {
      // Typically used with Federation identity with MSI
      "SourceType": "SignedAssertionFromManagedIdentity",
      "ManagedIdentityClientId": "55..55"
    }
  ],
  "SendX5C": false,

  "AllowWebApiToBeAuthorizedByACL": false,

  //"Audience": "Audience of your web API",
  "Audiences": [
     "33..33"
  ],

  "Scopes": [ "api://my-api.azurewebsites.net/44..44/MyApi.Read" ]
},

// Downstream APIs
"DownstreamApis": [
  {
    "MicrosoftGraphApi": {
      "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
      "Scopes": [ "user.read" ]
    }
  }
]

As a note, while I have the graph api configured here, I'm not actually calling it yet
I'm pretty sure I'm just missing some config value to make the token work with the downstream api, but I'm not sure what it is.  The MSFT documentation only shows you how to configure the upstream application but now the downstream API itself.
